# Android - Call another application inside my application

Tags: android

It´s possible call another application with startActivity(...) but my Activity continues with the focus? In the top of the screen?

Comment: No, that is not possible. Only 1 Activity has focus at any moment. If you start a new Activity (doens't matter from which application), your Activity will lose focus.

Answer (score 0):

> It´s possible call another application with startActivity(...) but my Activity continues with the focus? In the top of the screen?

Simply not possible but if you are looking to  start the activity of another application that you can do but that will be on the top of the screen.

Package name => Application package name which you want to start the activity of.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("packagename","Activity.java"));   
startActivity(intent);
```